# having some db design issue about efficiency

Tags: sql, database, uml

I'm new to db I have some issue with my diagrams. A mechanician needs a list of tools to repair a car and this tools might have other tools in it.

let's say that a mechanician needs these tools to be able to repair a motor

5x screw driver

---

1x hammer

---

1x [Craftman's box #56](http://toolguyd.com/craftsman-56pc-universal-mechanics-tool-set-review/)

---

my concern is for the  Craftman's box cause it has also other mechanician tools. Cause for this repair (motor) the mechanician might need only the box but for an other car it might only need a wrench that is inside the Craftman's box #56. It looks a bit like a reflexive association

Right now all the tools list are in the table MechanicianTools so all the tool inside the Craftman's box #56 are in the table MechanicianTools.

So in jquery (or any other program code) if I look for a tool I will look in the MechanicianTools but I'm wondering if the request will be slow cause this table might have over 5000 tools? Or if it's the way that I built the db that will makes it slow?

I don't know if the name of my table or properly choose cause it seems a bit confuse for me.
[image]

Comment: is there an other way to design it?

Comment: I don't understand how you can represent a many-to-many relation with only a single ID in each table. Please post some sample records.